# "Package installer keeps stopping" error when trying to uninstall Zoom Android app

Tags: uninstallation, zoom-cloud-meetings

I have a Nokia 6.1 Plus running Android 10. I am unable to uninstall the Zoom Android app. When I try to uninstall, I receive an error message "Package installer keeps stopping".

[image: Error message screenshot]

I don't get the error while uninstalling/installing other downloaded apps.

How to uninstall this app?

Comment: Uninstall from Play store?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling from play store worked for me !